# How to access the environment variables from inside ServiceBusAttribute constructor?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm having an azure function that is binded to a service bus, I'm using it like this:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
[ServiceBus("myqueueortopicname", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<string> messages)
```

I'm trying to make the service bus queue name to be configurable and to be taken from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyMessageBusQueueName")`

With

```
[ServiceBus(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyMessageBusQueueName"), Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<string> messages)`
```

**local.Settings.json**:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "MyMessageBusQueueName": "myqueueortopicname",
        "ServiceBusConnection": "..."
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

But I'm having an error of:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
> or array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the binding expression by wrapping the environment variable name with `%`. Define the queue name as `%MyMessageBusQueueName%` which would bind to environment variable

```
[ServiceBus("%MyMessageBusQueueName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<string> messages)
```

Read about binding expression at Microsoft documentation ---[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings).